# RAMFS mounting program

Tags: c, linux, unix

I rewrote a bash script into a standalone C program for mounting the current directory into the ramfs. However I still use "system()" for some of the functions. The only thing that still bothers me is the use of C mount function. In my code I call it with a system call but I want to know what is the right use in my case for C`s system.

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    (void) argc; // unused

    bool matched_result = false;

    // extra size
     char pwd[512]={0};
     getcwd(pwd, sizeof(pwd)/sizeof(pwd[0]));

     printf("Current working dir is: %s\n", pwd);

    // Check is already mounted ramfs on the current directory.
    // The beter way is manual parsing.
    // in order to avoid that process we have to write dirwalker
    // to list all mounted fses but for now will use this one
    FILE* mntstatus = popen("mount", "r");

    // assume no more than 512 chars per line
    char buff[512]={0};

    while (fgets(buff, 512, mntstatus) != NULL) {
        char* match = strchr(buff, '/');
        // trim 3 whitespaces from the end
        trim_end(match, ' ', 3);
        if (strcmp(match, pwd)==0) {
            printf("Match: [%s]\n", match);
            matched_result = true;
            break; // no need to search more
        }
    }

    // our cwd is not mounted
    if (!matched_result) {
        // empty, ok we can mount here
        // just efective-uid is not enough for mount
        // i need real-uid
        setuid(0);

        int res = mount_filesystem(pwd, "ramfs", "ramfs", 0, "rw", 0);
        //int res = system("mount -t ramfs ramfs `pwd`");
        if (res == 0) {
            printf("Mount ok\n");
            // convert to octals
            int octal_perms = strtol(g_Permissions, 0, 8);
            if (chmod(pwd, octal_perms) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: error in chmod(%s, %s) - %d (%s)\n",
                        argv[0], // program
                        pwd,    // current dir
                        g_Permissions, // with permissions
                        errno,          // Ermac :)
                        strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }

        } else {
            printf("Mount failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Dude you are ok!\n");
    }

    return 0;
    }


     void trim_end(char *str, const char delim, int count)
     {
     char* begin = str;
     char* end = &str[strlen(str)-1];
    int i=0;
    while ((i < count) && ( begin != end)) {
        if (*end == delim) {
            i++;
        }
        *end-- = 0;
    }
}


void register_exit_callback(cbAtExit ex)
{
    atexit(ex);
}

int mount_filesystem(const char *src, const char *tgt, const char *fstype, unsigned long flags,
                     const char *mode, const char *uid)
{
    char mode_uid[256]={0};
    if((mode != NULL) && (uid != NULL)) {
        sprintf(mode_uid, "mode=%s,uid=%s", mode, uid);
    }

    int result = mount(src, tgt, fstype, flags, mode_uid);
    // handle result outside
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. In the code you supplied the only call to `system()` is commented out. Are you having problems getting it to work without `system()`? Is the call to `mount()` failing?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the system call with my C function. My C function options are probably incorrect.

Comment: Use perror to print the error you get when it fails. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror

Comment: Will do that later and will report the message.

Comment: Your first 2 args to `mount` are swapped. The first should be `"ramfs"` (it can actually be any string at all when you're mounting a ramfs), and the second should be the mount point pathname. `mount_filesystem` has sensible names for its arguments, so I think what needs to be changed is the call to it: try `mount_filesystem("ramfs", pwd, "ramfs", 0, "rw", 0);`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thank you, that did it. I missused my own function, silly me.